# avoiding overflow errors in a clock program

Tags: c#, console, stack-overflow, clock

Hey so I'm a beginning coder, and I'm trying to make a console clock program in Visual Studio. It works, but after about 2 hours it throws a stack overflow error, due to the clock running on an infinite loop. Here's my code-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string hourInput;
        static string minuteInput;
        static string yearInput;
        static string dayInput;
        static string monthInput;

        static int saveMonth;
        static int saveYear;
        static int saveDay;
        static int saveSeconds;
        static int saveMinutes;
        static int saveHours;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the current hour");
            hourInput = (Console.ReadLine());
            saveHours = Int32.Parse(hourInput);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the current minute");
            minuteInput = (Console.ReadLine());
            saveMinutes = Int32.Parse(minuteInput);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the current day");
            dayInput = (Console.ReadLine());
            saveDay = Int32.Parse(dayInput);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the current month in numerical form");
            monthInput = (Console.ReadLine());
            saveMonth = Int32.Parse(minuteInput);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the current year");
            yearInput = (Console.ReadLine());
            saveYear = Int32.Parse(yearInput);


            Update();
        }

       static void Update()
        {
            Counter();
        }

        static void Counter()
        {
                int days = 1;
                int minutes = 0;
                int hours = 1;
                int Seconds = 0;
                int months = 1;
                int years = 2015;
                bool dayOver = false;

                Seconds = saveSeconds;
                minutes = saveMinutes;

                if (saveHours > hours)
                {
                    hours = saveHours;
                }

                if (saveYear > years)
                {
                    years = saveYear;
                }

                if (saveMonth > months)
                {
                    months = saveMonth;
                }

                if (saveDay > days)
                {
                    days = saveDay;
                }

                Seconds++;

                if (Seconds == 60)
                {
                    minutes++;
                    Seconds = 0;
                }

                if (minutes == 60)
                {
                    hours++;
                    minutes = 0;
                }

                if (hours > 12)
                {
                    if (dayOver == true)
                    {
                        days++;
                        dayOver = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dayOver = true;
                    }
                    hours = 1;
                }

                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine(days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + Seconds);

                saveSeconds = Seconds;
                saveMinutes = minutes;
                saveHours = hours;

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

So is there any way to run an infinite loop without throwing a stack overflow? Keep in mind I'm a beginning coder so it can't be too complex. I know that there are other ways to do a clock program but this is the way I want to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a StackOverflow because you are recursively calling your methods.

Every time you call a method, it gets pushed on to the call stack.

If you use a `while` loop instead, the only method present on the call stack (that we care about) will be the method containing the while loop, thus, no stack overflows.